# Excel 2013 VBA display 4 digits years with 2 digits weeks

Tags: vba, excel

Goodafternoon all,

Currently, I'm trying to fill a table with the following in the first row, which is needed for the VLOOKUP. I would like to have this row defined as `"yyyy-ww"`, so for this week `"2016-15"`. This works fine, however when it is earlier in the year, the weeks will be only 1 digit, `"2016-1"` instead of the expected `"2016-01"`. Formatting does not work unfortunately.

Can anyone please help me out?

The formula is basically putting `year, "-", current week` together, then shifting up to 12 weeks minus (so, we're in week 15 now, I would like to have week 03 to 15 displayed). How do I get the weeks displayed in the right format?

```
 Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-12)"
    Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-11)"
    Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-10)"
    Range("A7").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-9)"
    Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-8)"
    Range("A9").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-7)"
    Range("A10").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-6)"
    Range("A11").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-5)"
    Range("A12").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-4)"
    Range("A13").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-3)"
    Range("A14").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-2)"
    Range("A15").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-1)"
    Range("A16").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7))"
```

Comment: Try out the Format function: [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/gg251755.aspx)

Comment: Already tried the format function, but it did not work as far as I know. Where would I need to place it in the formula?

Comment: I don't know exactly because I've got some trouble to read your formula, but basically you have to put it at the point where you was inserting your week, because you want to change the format of your week from "1" to "01".

Comment: The week is coming from the part starting with INT
'INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have the desired format and shorten the code with the following

```
Range("A4").Resize(12).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"", TEXT(  INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-(12-rows(R4:R)) ,""00""))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format you integer to allways have 2 digits.

```
Format(iMyInt, "00")
```

Comment: Ok, this one goes over my head unfortunately. How would I code this in the above formula?

Comment: Right before u read or calculate the week. I think the problem is that u create a string out of 3 parts. One part of this string is causing problems with the format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to bring your formula into VBA, you can use `DatePart` to more efficiently extract the week number, and then `Format` to get the leading zero you desire.

The last line of your formula would become as follows:

```
Range("A16").FormulaR1C1 = Year(Now()) & "-" & Format(DatePart("ww", Now()), "00")
```

while the first would be

```
Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = Year(Now()) & "-" & Format(DatePart("ww", Now()) - 12, "00")
```

Calling `DatePart("ww",Now())` tells VBA to return  the week part of todays date, wrapping this in `Format` tells it to output it in the format you seek.

**A word of warning, however** -  this seems to return a value of 16 for today's date, so you may need to check your week definition against that used in `DatePart`, if you choose to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding the formulae in VBA, you may be better off getting the field value there instead:

```
range("A4").value = format(now,"yyyy") & "-" & format(format(dateadd("ww",-x,now),"ww"),"00")
```

where x is the number of weeks ago you want.

However, if you are intending to use the formula so that it will update without any interference then you can use the TEXT() function in the same way that VBA uses Format().

```
 Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY()),""-"",TEXT((INT((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)-12),"00"))"
```

A word of caution. VLookup works off the underlying field value, so if you are looking up from a date displayed as 2016-15, then the lookup will still fail.  In this case, you might need to make sure that both dates are set to the first day of the working week to ensure a match.